# How do symbolic links affect the way Python finds modules?

Tags: python

The environment variable `PYTHONPATH` is set to `$HOME/lib/python`.

The file tree in `$PYTHONPATH` looks like this

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
```

both files are empty.

Now I create a simple script containing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print __file__
import bar
```

and save it as `baz.py`. If I run the script anywhere other than
in `$PYTHONPATH/foo` it fails to locate module `bar`.

However if I move the file to `$PYTHONPATH/foo` and create a symbolic link
to that file, I can run it from anywhere. For example:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ ln -s $PYTHONPATH/foo/baz.py baz
$ ./baz
./baz
$
```

Yet `__file__` is set to `./baz`. So how does Python find module bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `foo` is in PYTHONPATH then `from foo import bar` should work anywhere.

Symbolic link is resolved to the path it points to. Then Python gets the real file and the import logic begins.